# Why do mllib word2vec word vectors only have 100 elements?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, word2vec

I have a word2vec model that I created in PySpark. The model is saved as a .parquet file. I want to be able to access and query the model (or the words and word vectors) using vanilla Python because I am building a flask app that will allow a user to enter words of interest for finding synonyms.

I've extracted the words and word vectors, but I've noticed that while I have approximately 7000 unique words, my word vectors have a length of 100. For example, here are two words "serious" and "breaks". Their vectors only have a length of 100. Why is this? How is it able to then reconstruct the entire vector space with only 100 values for each word? Is it simply only giving me the top 100 or the first 100 values?

```
    vectors.take(2)
    Out[48]: 
    [Row(word=u'serious', vector=DenseVector([0.0784, -0.0882, -0.0342, -0.0153, 0.0223, 0.1034, 0.1218, -0.0814, -0.0198, -0.0325, -0.1024, -0.2412, -0.0704, -0.1575, 0.0342, -0.1447, -0.1687, 0.0673, 0.1248, 0.0623, -0.0078, -0.0813, 0.0953, -0.0213, 0.0031, 0.0773, -0.0246, -0.0822, -0.0252, -0.0274, -0.0288, 0.0403, -0.0419, -0.1122, -0.0397, 0.0186, -0.0038, 0.1279, -0.0123, 0.0091, 0.0065, 0.0884, 0.0899, -0.0479, 0.0328, 0.0171, -0.0962, 0.0753, -0.187, 0.034, -0.1393, -0.0575, -0.019, 0.0151, -0.0205, 0.0667, 0.0762, -0.0365, -0.025, -0.184, -0.0118, -0.0964, 0.1744, 0.0563, -0.0413, -0.054, -0.1764, -0.087, 0.0747, -0.022, 0.0778, -0.0014, -0.1313, -0.1133, -0.0669, 0.0007, -0.0378, -0.1093, -0.0732, 0.1494, -0.0815, -0.0137, 0.1009, -0.0057, 0.0195, 0.0085, 0.025, 0.0064, 0.0076, 0.0676, 0.1663, -0.0078, 0.0278, 0.0519, -0.0615, -0.0833, 0.0643, 0.0032, -0.0882, 0.1033])),
     Row(word=u'breaks', vector=DenseVector([0.0065, 0.0027, -0.0121, 0.0296, -0.0467, 0.0297, 0.0499, 0.0843, 0.1027, 0.0179, -0.014, 0.0586, 0.06, 0.0534, 0.0391, -0.0098, -0.0266, -0.0422, 0.0188, 0.0065, -0.0309, 0.0038, -0.0458, -0.0252, 0.0428, 0.0046, -0.065, -0.0822, -0.0555, -0.0248, -0.0288, -0.0016, 0.0334, -0.0028, -0.0718, -0.0571, -0.0668, -0.0073, 0.0658, -0.0732, 0.0976, -0.0255, -0.0712, 0.0899, 0.0065, -0.04, 0.0964, 0.0356, 0.0142, 0.0857, 0.0669, -0.038, -0.0728, -0.0446, 0.1194, -0.056, 0.1022, 0.0459, -0.0343, -0.0861, -0.0943, -0.0435, -0.0573, 0.0229, 0.0368, 0.085, -0.0218, -0.0623, 0.0502, -0.0645, 0.0247, -0.0371, -0.0785, 0.0371, -0.0047, 0.0012, 0.0214, 0.0669, 0.049, -0.0294, -0.0272, 0.0642, -0.006, -0.0804, -0.06, 0.0719, -0.0109, -0.0272, -0.0366, 0.0041, 0.0556, 0.0108, 0.0624, 0.0134, -0.0094, 0.0219, 0.0164, -0.0545, -0.0055, -0.0193]))]
```

Any thoughts on the best way to reconstruct this model in vanilla python?

Comment: Vectors have length 100 because this is the default model parameter and you most like didn't change it.

Comment: Oh... of course. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just to improve on the comment by zero323, for anyone else who arrives here.
Word2Vec has a default setting to create word vectors of 100dims. To change this:

```
model = Word2Vec(sentences, size=300)
```

when initializing the model will create vectors of 300 dimensions.

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem lays with your minCount parameter value for the Word2Vec model.
If this value is too high, less words get used in the training of the model resulting in a words vector of only 100.
7000 unique words is not a lot.
Try setting the minCount lower than the default 5.

```
model.setMinCount(value)
```

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.ml.html?highlight=word2vec#pyspark.ml.feature.Word2Vec

Comment: This is wrong - the correct answer is the comment by zero323 above